# Handling categorical variables in sklearn with one-hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Can someone help with any existing Python class for categorical encoder for `sklearn` that ticks the following checkboxes?

1. pandas friendly - option to return a dataframe
2. should be able to drop 1 column in one-hot encoding
3. handling of unseens categories in test data.
4. compatible with sklearn Pipeline object.

Comment: Such a thing does not exist natively in `pandas` or `sklearn`. However, with a little coding, you can wrap `OneHotEncoder` to do what you want.

Comment: yes. i couldn't find something on these lines..

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [pandas.get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

See the following example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col_a":['cat','dog','cat','mouse','mouse','cat'], 'col_b':[10,14,16,18,20,22], 'col_c':['a','a','a','b','b','a']})

# `drop_first` parameter will drop the one categorical column
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['col_a','col_c'], drop_first=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  col_b  col_a_dog  col_a_mouse  col_c_b                                                                                               
0     10          0            0        0                                                                                               
1     14          1            0        0                                                                                               
2     16          0            0        0                                                                                               
3     18          0            1        1                                                                                               
4     20          0            1        1                                                                                               
5     22          0            0        0
```

It covers first 2 conditions that you mentioned.

For 3rd condition you can do the following.

- create the dummies on the training data
  `dummy_train = pd.get_dummies(train)`
- create the dummies in the new (unseen data)
  `dummy_new = pd.get_dummies(new_data)`
- re-index the new data to the columns of the training data, filling the missing values with 0
  `dummy_new.reindex(columns = dummy_train.columns, fill_value=0)`

Effectively any new features which are categorical will not go into the classifier, but I think that should not cause problems as it would not know what to do with them.

Comment: Sorry. I am aware of this. Looking for something in sklearn standards that can fit into pipelines.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar I believe OP means a `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` object.

Comment: @solver149 you should add that info in your question.